# Необходимо ли тире после слова "квартира"?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Твоя квартира (–) прям проходной двор.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Твоя кварИра — **прям** проходной двОр. Твоя квартИра — **просто** проходной двОр.*

***Прям, просто***  — частицы. По правилам Розенталя при наличии частиц между подлежащим и сказуемым тире не ставится, но возможна постановка **интонационного тире**.

В данном случае (в **простом предложении** подобной структуры) пауза и тире необходимы для обозначения состава предложения и выделения подлежащего, иначе фраза будет неудобной для прочтения.

Однако **в сложном предложении** расстановка ударений может меняться, и тогда тире не ставится, например: *Твоя кварира **прям** проходной двОр, приходит кто и когда захОчет.*

**Правила:**

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

Тире не ставится: 4) если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит вводное слово, иногда — наречие, союз, **частица**:  *Март **только** начало весны.* Но тире может ставиться при интонационном членении предложения и логическом подчеркивании слов.

ПАС под ред. Лопатина http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106#pp106
Примечание. Тире может не ставиться, если в письменной речи отражено произношение с логическим ударением на сказуемом.